# Radio-button can't focus in Rails with form-for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, form-for

I want to implement that the radio button can focus when it been clicked.

### Here is the GIF:

[image]

### Code

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @question] do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category_id %>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <label class="btn btn-default <%= (category.id == f.object.category_id)? 'active' : '' %>">
          <%= f.radio_button :category_id, category.id %>
          <%= category.title %>
        </label>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

**Any idea, please.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using bootstrap 4, try to check that you properly including js files

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/README.md

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
```